# Why is my C# native messaging host hanging when reading a message sent by a Firefox browser extension?

Tags: c#, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I have seen several C# native messaging host examples on stackoverflow that use this code to read a message from Chrome:

```
var stdin = Console.OpenStandardInput();
var length = 0;

var lengthBytes = new byte[4];
stdin.Read(lengthBytes, 0, 4);
length = BitConverter.ToInt32(lengthBytes, 0);

var buffer = new char[length];
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stdin))
{
  while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
  {
    reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
  }
}
```

I used that code as the basis for my `ReadMessage` method and it seemed to work in both Chrome and Firefox. However, I am now sending longer messages (about 2K), and `reader.Peek()` is hanging after the first pass through the loop.

1. Why is `reader.Peek()` hanging?
2. Why does it hang when reading from Firefox but not Chrome?
3. What can I do to avoid the hang?

Answer (score 0):

Change the loop as follows:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stdin))
{
  var offset = 0;
  while (offset < length && reader.Peek() >= 0)
  {
    offset += reader.Read(buffer, offset, length - offset);
  }
}
```

The key change is using `offset < length` in the `while` condition so that `reader.Peek()` is not called after all the expected characters have been read. This version also handles `reader.Read()` returning less than `length` characters such that multiple loops are required to read the entire message. I do not know if that can occur. In general, though, a stream's read method may not return all the requested characters.

The updated loop is working, so I have answered the last of my questions, *What can I do to avoid the hang?*

I assume that `reader.Peek()` hangs when reading a Firefox message because of some difference between how Chrome and Firefox handle the stream on their side. A better understanding of that would probably answer my first two questions.

I still don't understand why all the samples I found on stackoverflow and elsewhere used the first version of the read loop and no one else mentioned hangs. I know there is a lot more attention given to Chrome than to Firefox, so that could be it, or perhaps most applications that use native messaging are using short messages, or both.